# Argument of #selector does not refer to an '@objc' method, property or initializer

Tags: swift4, xcode10

Below is my code I'm following an online tutorial but I'm getting the above error.

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {



    @IBOutlet var xField: [MyImageView]!

    var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        appDelegate.mpcHandling.gettingPeerConnection(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        appDelegate.mpcHandling.gettingSession()
        appDelegate.mpcHandling.showingSelf(show: true)

        //handling peer state notification

        //getting error for the below mentioned line

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector("peerChangedNotification:"), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("handleReceivedNotification:"), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveNotification"), object: nil)

        mainLogicField()

    }

    @objc func peerChangedNotification(notification:NSNotification){
        let userInfo = NSDictionary(dictionary: notification.userInfo!)

        let state = userInfo.object(forKey: "state") as! Int

        if state != MCSessionState.connecting.rawValue{
            //Now we inform user that we have connected
            self.navigationItem.title = "Connected Successfully"
        }
    }


    @IBAction func getConnected(_ sender: Any) {

        if appDelegate.mpcHandling.gameSession != nil {
            appDelegate.mpcHandling.gettingBrowser()
            appDelegate.mpcHandling.browser.delegate = self

            self.present(appDelegate.mpcHandling.browser, animated: true, completion: nil
            )

        }

    }




    func mainLogicField() {
        for index in 0 ... xField.count - 1 {

            let recognizeGestureTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fieldTapped")

            recognizeGestureTouch.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

            xField[index].addGestureRecognizer(recognizeGestureTouch)
        }
    }

    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        appDelegate.mpcHandling.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        appDelegate.mpcHandling.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Not sure what is wrong as I have used #selector and @objc for my function as well.
Online tutorial just made use of NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "peerChangedNotification:", name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)
without adding #selector, but if I remove #selector then it gives me a warning stating "No method declared with Objective-C selector 'peerChangedNotification'".
I'm trying to connect the 2 devices using mutipeer

Comment: You are using selector syntax wrong.

Comment: Hint: `#selector` doesn't take a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Selector() :**  It receives string/ string-literal as a parameter. It was used previously and `#selector` is upgraded definition.

**#selector :** You are trying to pass a string in `#selector` whereas it takes Objective-C type function reference. Correct example is:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(peerChangedNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name("MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)
```